# Create the Mapping and Display Runs For Each Over and I Also Add First Over Runs in the Sum of Second Over Runs and Same for Third Over

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Source table `Cricket_Score`:

| Overs | Balls | Runs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 4 |

I Want to an output like this:

| Overs | Total_Runs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 39 |

**Description: -** For First Over means First 6 Balls I Want Sum of First 6 Balls that is 10. and For Second 6 Balls I Want Sum of First 6 Balls [Over] + Second 6 Balls That is 25 [10 + 15 = 25]. and For Third 6 Balls I Want Sum of First 6 Balls [Over] + Second 6 Balls + Third ^ Balls That is 39 [10 + 15 + 14 = 39].

**Note:** - 6 balls means one over.

How to create a mapping in for this scenario in Informatica / which logic should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will assume your data is **EXACTLY** like you have shown in your question. If its not like this in source then it will be a major issue. If its a table where data is not sorted, it will be an issue.

Solution -

1. Create an expression transformation with below ports - in below order. in - input port, v_variable port, out_* output port

```
in_balls
in_runs  
in_overs
v_cumulative_runs= in_runs+ iif(isnull(v_cumulative_run),0,v_cumulative_run)
out_total_runs=v_cumulative_runs
out_overs=in_overs
```

2. Use an aggregator -

```
in_total_runs
in_out_overs -- group by this port
out_total_runs = max(in_total_runs)
```

3. Attach in_out_overs and out_total_runs links to target.

Comment: This Logic is Not Working. Result Shows Like Below: -
In the Table there are total 18 Records means Total 3 Overs.
And In Target Table: - Overs Column it will Display [0] for all 12 Records.
And For Runs Column it will Display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.
Like this. What should I do Now? is there any Other Logic? to Solve this Problem?

Comment: I Update the Table Structure Please see Once and Provide some Logic for this, Because this Question ask to me by Interviewer.

Comment: Thanx a Lot it's Perfectly working.